# Doesn't add into struct

Tags: c, struct

How do I make an array of struct and how can I call them?  I want to make a struct list of drivers and their companies. Right now code only stores one struct but makes an error after I try to store another one. It stops at somebody = realloc(somebody, (sizeof(struct driver) * (j + 1))); for some reason.

```
struct Timer {
    int hour;
    int minutes;
    int seconds;
};
struct driver {
    char* name;
    char* company;
    int total;
    struct Timer time;
};

char AddName(struct driver* somebody, int j) {
    char name[30];
    char company[30];
    scanf("%s", name);
    scanf("%s", company);
    somebody = realloc(somebody, (sizeof(struct driver) * (j + 1)));
    somebody[j].company = company;
    somebody[j].name = name;
    somebody[j].time.seconds = 0;
    somebody[j].time.minutes = 0;
    somebody[j].time.hour = 0;
    somebody[j].total = 0;
    return somebody;
}

int main(void) {
    char text[100];
    int num_drivers = 0;
    struct driver* somebody = malloc(sizeof(struct driver));
    printf("Enter text\n");
    scanf("%s",text);
    printf("-------------------------------------------------\n");
    while (text != "Q") {
        if (strcmp(text,"A") == 0) {
            somebody = AddName(somebody,num_drivers);
            num_drivers++;
        }
```

```
A Sam Renault 
A Frank Volvo
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and make the code complete to be compiled. Describe what is the exact problem. I suggest to parse the whole input in `main()` and pass `name` and `company` as function arguments to `AddName`. In `AddName` you have to store copies of the string values in your structure. One option would be `somebody[j].company = strdup(company);`

Comment: In `AddName` you assign the address of local variables created on the stack and only valid during function call to `name` and `company` field of `struct driver`. You can use suggestion of previous comment and bind a copy of `name` and  `company` input to `struct driver` record. However, don't forget to free memory of the copy later. Another possibility is to use character arrays for `name` and `company` in `struct driver` and assign input using `strcpy/strncpy` or by `scanf` directly.